# Linear independence of complex polynomials and a "sum of squares" conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, sums-of-squares, spinor

This will take me some time to explain. Let $n \geq 2$ be a fixed integer. Let $p_i(z)$, for $i = 1,\ldots,n$ be $n$ nonzero complex polynomials of degree at most $n-1$. I am interested in reformulating whether or not the $n$ complex polynomials are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$, using the so called "squaring map", which is familiar to people working with spinors. It is a quadratic map which maps spinors to vectors. I will define everything.

For $i = 1, \ldots, n$, write

$$ p_i(z) = \prod_{j \neq i} L_{ij}(z) $$

where $j$ runs over the values from $1$ to $n$ that are different from $i$, and each $L_{ij}(z)$ is a (nonzero) complex polynomial of degree at most $1$, so that

$$L_{ij}(z) = a_{ij} z + b_{ij}.$$

Of course, for a fixed $i$, the $L_{ij}$ are not uniquely determined. For instance these linear factors can be permuted, or you could for instance scale them differently. In the end, our construction will be independent of such ambiguities.

Given a nonzero polynomial

$$L(z) = az + b$$

of degree at most $1$, one can form a nonzero element of $\psi_L \in \mathbb{C}^2$ out of its coefficients, namely

$$\psi_L = \left( \begin{array}{c} a \\ b \end{array} \right).$$

We can now define the "squaring" $Sq(L)$ of the polynomial $L(z)$ to be

$$ Sq(L) := \psi_L \psi_L^* = \left( \begin{array}{cc} |a|^2 & a \bar{b} \\ \bar{a} b & |b|^2 \end{array} \right). $$

We also define the "squaring" of a nonzero complex polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ to be
the symmetric tensor product (over $\mathbb{C}$) of the squarings of its linear factors. So for instance,

$$ Sq(p_i) := \odot_{j \neq i} Sq(L_{ij}). $$

I should say what I mean by the symmetric tensor product. Each $Sq(L_{ij})$ has an index up and an index down, with each of these indices taking values in $\{1,2\}$. In order to define $Sq(p_i)$, first form the outer product (or tensor product if you prefer) of all the $Sq(L_{ij})$, for $j \neq i$, then completely symmetrize all the indices up together, and completely symmetrize all the indices down together. Since each index can only take on $2$ possible values, this will result in a tensor, which can be viewed simply as an $n \times n$ matrix, one index up (resp. down) which corresponds to the various values of the symmetrized indices up (resp. down).

One can check that $Sq(p_i)$ is indeed well defined, despite the ambiguities in the definitions of the factors $L_{ij}$.

Define the following "sum of squares":

$$ S := \sum_{i=1}^n Sq(p_i),$$

which can be thought of as an $n \times n$ matrix, by the remarks above.

I conjecture that the $p_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, are linearly independent over $\mathbb{C}$ iff their "sum of squares" $S$ is nonsingular.

For $n = 2$, this is straightforward. I did some numerical simulations for $n = 3$, which seem to confirm my conjecture. However, I did not do any numerical simulations for $n > 3$. So it could be false for $n = 4$ perhaps. I am not sure yet.

If someone has any comments and/or, better, knows how to prove/disprove my conjecture, then please share your knowledge.

Comment: $\DeclareMathOperator\Sym{Sym}$To check that I'm understanding the symmetric tensor product correctly, with $\Sym(x_1 \otimes \dotsb \otimes x_n) = \sum_{\sigma \in n!} x_{\sigma(1)} \otimes \dotsb \otimes x_{\sigma(n)}$:  $\bigodot (a \otimes b) = \Sym(\bigotimes a) \otimes \Sym(\bigotimes b)$, where we're identifying $2\times2$ complex matrices with elements of $(\mathbb C^2)^* \otimes \mathbb C^2$?

Comment: @LSpice, yes, what you wrote agrees with what I meant.

Comment: Sorry for a dumb question, but is $$\operatorname{Sq}((az+b)(cz+d)) = \operatorname{Sq}(az+b) \odot \operatorname{Sq}(cz+d) = \psi_L \psi_L^* \odot \psi_M \psi_M^* = (1/2) (\psi_L \psi_L^* \otimes \psi_M\psi_M^* + \psi_M\psi_M^* \otimes \psi_L\psi_L^*)?$$ Are we also supposed to also add $\psi_L\psi_M^*$ and $\psi_M\psi_L^*$? Or am I way off base.

Comment: @ZachTeitler, it is a smart question actually and to the point. You are supposed to also add $\psi_L \psi_M^*$ and $\psi_M \psi_L^*$ too, yes. Your comment actually gave me an idea how to prove it, I think, but I have to double check. It is actually a completeness relation, as the physicists call it, except instead of getting the identity, I get something non-singular. I can write more when I find some time. Thank you!

Comment: I think it ends up being something trivial. Sort of like, when you have nonzero vectors $v_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and you consider the sum of the $v_i v_i^*$, then you would be adding up rank $1$ matrices, and if the vectors are linearly independent, then the sum of the $v_i v_i^*$ is nonsingular. And if the $v_i$ are linearly dependent, then the sum of the $v_i v_i^*$ does not have full rank, and so is singular. Yes, I think that's it. Thank you! I have to go now, I will take care of editing this post etc. in a few hours.

Answer (score 1):

First we discuss a small lemma, from which my conjectured equivalence will follow.

Let $v_i \in \mathbb{C}^n$, for $i = 1,\ldots,n$ be nonzero vectors. Let

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i v_i^*,$$

which is an hermitian $n \times n$ matrix. I claim that the $v_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, are linearly independent (over $\mathbb{C}$) iff $S$ is nonsingular.

Let $g$ be the $n \times n$ matrix having $v_j$ as its $j$-th column. Then from the definition of $S$, we have

$$S = gg^*$$

which implies that $\det(S) = | \det(g) |^2$, from which the claim follows.

In order to prove my conjectured equivalence in my post above, all one needs to do is apply this lemma to with $v_i = p_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. In other words, we let $v_i$ represent the coefficients of the polynomial $p_i$. One can then check that $p_i p_i^*$ is, up to some combinatorial factors $\binom{n-1}{k}$, depending on one's conventions, nothing but what I called the symmetric tensor product of the $Sq(L_{ij})$, which is possibly called something else in the literature. I have explained precisely in my post and in the comments below what I meant by that notion. If one thinks about it, then one would realize that $p_i p_i^*$ is nothing but what I have defined and called $Sq(p_i)$ (up to possibly the combinatorial factors that I have mentioned, which do not affect whether or not the $n \times n$ matrix $S$ is singular or not.

The lemma mentioned in this answer, applied with $v_i = p_i$, for $i = 1, \ldots, n$, and the observation above, together imply my "sum of squares" conjecture in my post above.

So it ended up being something rather trivial. However, could someone please let me know what this notion of "symmetric tensor product" of matrices is really called in the literature, if it has been studied before, and how the eigenvalues of the resulting $n \times n$ matrix, representing this notion of "symmetric tensor product" of $n-1$ $2 \times 2$ matrices, can be obtained from the eigenvalues of the original $2 \times 2$ matrices (assuming this can be done)?